# NAT not working when using iptables with coreos

Tags: router, iptables, nat, coreos

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Sat Jun  4 12:36:07 2016
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [222:16966]
:INPUT ACCEPT [222:16966]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [144:15162]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [144:15162]
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Jun  4 12:36:07 2016
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Sat Jun  4 12:36:07 2016
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [6:1714]
:INPUT ACCEPT [6:1714]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [21:1276]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [20:1200]
-A POSTROUTING -o enp2s0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Jun  4 12:36:07 2016
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.21 on Sat Jun  4 12:36:07 2016
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [167:13042]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [108:10762]
-A FORWARD -i enp1s0 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Sat Jun  4 12:36:07 2016
```

I can't seem to make NAT to work on a coreos latest barebone machine, the following is the private network

```
        [Match]
        Name=enp1s0

        [Network]
        DNS=8.8.8.8
        DNS=8.8.4.4
        Address=192.168.1.1/24
```

and `enp2s0` is an additional connection that has internet access, the desired behaviour would be that a 2'nd machine could access the internet trough the `enp1s0` interface. I'll also post the network config of the second machine

```
    [Match]
    Name=enp1s0

    [Network]
    DNS=8.8.8.8
    DNS=8.8.4.4
    Address=192.168.1.111/24
    Gateway=192.168.1.1
```

Update:

```
core@x35a ~ $ ip route show
default via xxx.xxx.xxx dev enp2s0  proto static 
xxx.xxx.xxx/28 dev enp2s0  proto kernel  scope link  src xxx.xxx.xxx 
192.168.1.0/24 dev enp1s0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.1 
core@x35a ~ $
```

Comment: What is the routes?

Comment: There are written in the first codeblock

Comment: you can log the packege in postrouting chain:
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o enp2s0 -j LOG --log-prefix='[masq] '
This checks if the traffic pass.

Answer (score -1):

sysctl -a | grep forward? Sure you enabled forwarding?
I am not familiar with CoreOs in particular but I think you need to set some flag in order to forward traffic from one interface to another.